# Parallel use of Intel and Nvidia (eGPU) driver / Not Hybrid!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo X220 notebook with onboard Intel graphics.

I purchased a so called external PCIe GPU (GeForce GTX 560 Ti) which is connected via the card slot of my laptop.

Now I want to switch to the Nvidia driver on boot when the eGPU is connected. If it is not, I want to switch back to the intel driver.

I've written a little script doing the job: It places the nvidia xorg.conf on startup (on egpu) or removes it (on intel).

The problem is that the nvidia driver changes some libraries (and maybe more) so I can't use the intel driver. The following error message occurs in xorg.log:

```
(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

My question is: Does anybody know how to switch back to the intel driver without completely removing the nvidia driver? Do I have to change some symlinks or something like this?

Comment: These are the tools that exist for it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/108648/bumblebee-or-ironhide .  They're noted on all the Nvidia Optimus threads and may apply to your situation.

Comment: I don't think that this is what I'm looking for. As I said, it's not a classical hybrid thing. I don't want to use both the intel and the nvidia driver in one session. The driver should be chosen on startup and remain until next boot.

Comment: Yeah, you would choose intel all the time.  Then manually load the nvidia driver without associating it with xorg so you could do opencl

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu provides the Alternatives system which you can use to configure Nvidia or Intel (Mesa libGL) in this case.

See my answer to [No 3D support on Lenovo W520 with nVidia Optimus](https://askubuntu.com/q/107742/6969). You should run the mentioned `update-alternatives` and `ldconfig` commands before X is started.