# External graphics card (eGPU) on mPCIe is not detected in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, pci

I have HP 530 laptop (the one with 2.16 GHz Core Duo processor) with 3GB RAM and GMA950 iGPU, GTX 560 Ti and PE4C-PM3E V1.2 adapter (so I plug it to mPCIe where WiFi was before), which is said to support Linux.

Firstly, if that eGPU is plugged in and I power on the laptop, I see black screen and there is no reaction on input, e.g., on ctrl+alt+del. So I power on eGPU after I power on the laptop. In Windows 7 and 8 the eGPU is detected after I go to and the out of sleep mode but with the error 12 in the device manager meaning there is no enough of resources for PCI. In Windows XP the error code message is absent but still there is a message that the drivers are not installed in the device description so the eGPU is not seen normally anywhere, though CPU-Z can see it but with 128 MB or memory.

In Ubuntu 14.04 (in Knoppix 7.2 the same) after I return from sleep mode I don't hear high noisy sound from the eGPU, meaning that eGPU is detected somehow, but I could not find the eGPU anywhere in the system. When I try install drivers from nVidia site, it does not detect it. I installed drivers through

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime
```

said to be definitely working on Ubuntu, but that changed nothing.

Here is what lscpi shows:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
02:06.0 CardBus bridge: ENE Technology Inc CB1410 Cardbus Controller (rev 01)
02:08.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82562ET/EZ/GT/GZ - PRO/100 VE (LOM) Ethernet Controller Mobile (rev 01)
```

I hope that Ubuntu can manage PCI resources better than Windows. I saw that there is a better proceeding with GTX 560 Ti as eGPU [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131344/parallel-use-of-intel-and-nvidia-egpu-driver-not-hybrid). The difference is that I use another laptop and connect to mPCIe. The PE4C V1.2 itself is reported to be working greatly. I am new to Linux. I'll be glad to see any safe way to solve this problem.

Update:
Using

```
sudo lspci -H 1
```

showed me the eGPU with its sound card

```
10:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti] (rev a1)
10:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Now it seems I have to load them somehow.

Comment: For the following has worked:
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan"

Comment: The Problem is solved? If that is the case, consider to post your solution as answer. That is the way in AU to close a question. Also this will earn you reputation points. And last but not least: Someone else might profit from your description.

Comment: I wanted to do this but this didn't work for a while.

Answer (score 1):

The following has worked:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan"
```

But first you should be sure that you can see your device through direct hardware access.

```
sudo lspci -H 1
```

worked for me and

```
sudo lspci -H 2
```

did not.