# Intel HD 3000 not working in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus

My laptop is MSi GE620 DX and it has Nvidia Optimus technology. Intel and Nvidia gfx cards. However Ubuntu doesn´t even regonize my Intel HD 3000 at all!

I even tried Fedora 17 on my system and it did regonize Intel HD 3000 straight away. But not in Ubuntu. Can´t set the correct resolution, or run Gnome 3 for example. The card just isn´t regonized.

I tried install mesa-utils, but no, did not help.

I can´t use software that needs 3d in ubuntu, but in fedora, everything works.

Comment: The "culprit" here seems to be the Optimus technology. Have a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107742/no-3d-support-on-lenovo-w520-with-nvidia-optimus), it seems to be a similar problem, albeit on a different laptop.

Comment: I read just the other day that GPU switching ('nvidia optimus') doesnt work well at all on linux in general. I have heard that by using the latest 304 nvidia driver, support is improved, but i in no way recommend you use a bleeding edge driver.

Answer (score 1):

I've an Akoya MD 6634 with Nvidia Optimus Technology and it works fine with Ubuntu 12.04. The Installation was a little bit tricky. First, you have to boot with optin "nomodeset"; in other cases yo may get a black screen (see: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)).

After Installation has completed, there was no Gnome3 (always Fallback-mode). I installed "Bumblebee" - see here: http://bumblebee-project.org/; there is a discription for Ubuntu. After that, everything is fine; normally, Intel graphic is in use; to speed it up, i can use "optirun" and it get's much faster!